# QScrollArea: How to set the handle size?

Tags: qt, scrollbar

I'm designing this for a touchscreen, so the scrollbar handles need to be extra big, but so far, this is all I can get:

[image]

In the constructor of the list widget:

```
myScrollArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
myScrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
myScrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setFixedWidth(pitch_height);
myScrollArea->setWidget(this);
```

`pitch_height` is the size of the icons.  I figured that'd be about right for the scrollbar too.  Something roughly like this:

[image]

Comment: You could show an image of what you want to get.

Comment: @eyllanesc: I'm away from my computer right now, but I can probably photoshop something tomorrow.  I just want the scrollbar to be as wide as the icons.

Comment: It is always good to place what you have and what you want, and if it is something visual is better with images.

Comment: use of `QWidget` on mobile device (touch screen device) is a bit old fashioned. I would use QML.

Comment: @MarekR: It's actually a desktop PC with touch, permanently mounted in the sound booth of a youth center that I volunteer for.  Qt's built-in mouse interaction "just works" with that, so I'm using mouse events to handle the rest that I want it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use style sheets to modify scroll bar

```
QScrollBar:vertical {
    width: 100px;
}
```

[image: width]

Relevant documentation:

[Customizing QScrollBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar)

[Qt Style Sheets Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html)

Comment: I saw your example and thought, "Good start, but I also need the end buttons to be square at that size."  So I found how to set their height and added that too.  Then I wanted the arrow image to fill the button, and in the process of trying that I discovered that your code by itself actually does make the buttons square.  And I gave up on the arrow size; it's fine as it is.